# How do I get text from a calculated String to a TextView field?

Tags: java, android, textview

it seems like I am close, but I am missing something with this. I want to create a tip calculator where you enter the amount of your original bill, then click a % button (10, 15, or 20) which calculates your tip and places it into a TextView field, which represents your total bill (called finalBill) with tip added.

But I tried using `finalBill.setText(finalB.getText());`, but I get an error saying getText() is undefined. I have only set up the 10% button right now, but once I get it right, I will apply this code to the 15 and 20 methods too.

The original bill will be entered by the user as a double (although it's in an EditText field), the calculation (in the 10% button) needs to happen with doubles, and the final bill should be either a String or some text(?) so that it can fill the TextView field called finalBill. Please try to stick with the original code as much as possible, as I'm a beginner and get confused easily. Thanks for your help!

```
package com.example.nonitips;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText originalBill;
    public double billWithTip; 
    String billString;
    public TextView finalBill;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        originalBill = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.originalBill);
    }

    public void onTen (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tipping at 10%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        originalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double bill = Double.parseDouble(originalBill.getText().toString());
                billWithTip = (bill * 0.10) + bill;
                String billString = String.valueOf(billWithTip);
                finalBill = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalBill);
                finalBill.setText(billString.getText());
            }
        });

    }

    public void onFifteen (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tipping at 15%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onTwenty (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tipping at 20%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing "billString.getText()", billString is itself a string, use it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you were trying to use a String as if it was a TextView:

```
finalBill.setText(billString.getText());
```

but this is wrong.

This is correct:

```
finalBill.setText(billString);
```

There is another issue: you redeclare billString:

```
String billString = String.valueOf(billWithTip);
```

But you already declared in the beginning

```
String billString;
```

So, this is enough:

```
billString = String.valueOf(billWithTip);
```

And... to apply 10%, this is an overkill:

```
billWithTip = (bill * 0.10) + bill;
```

You just need to do so:

```
billWithTip = bill * 1.10;
```

And more:

The onClick listener isn't assigned to a Button... it's assigned to an EditText:

```
originalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
// ...
```

and originalBill is really an EditText:

```
public EditText originalBill;
// ...
originalBill = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.originalBill);
```

So, let me assume you have a button called `btnTenPct` in your layout:

Do this:

```
public Button btnTenPct;
// ...
btnTenPct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTenPct);
// ...
btnTenPct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Vyger, do you mean the .getText() method only works on a TextView variable? and that is why it did not work, because billString is a String?

Comment: Yes, correct. Strings don't have a getText method. Must be used "as they are"

Comment: Thanks, I did change it now, but the new calculated text is not showing up in the TextView field when I click the 10% button, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: Because the onClick listener isn't assigned to a Button... it's assigned to an EditText: `originalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` and originalBill is an EditText: `public EditText originalBill;`

Comment: Good tip about the 1.10 part too. I will learn to get more efficient one day! :)

Comment: Experience, my dear... Long years of experience... ;)

Comment: Of course, **I don't need to tell you** that it's the same with 1.15 and 1.20 for 15% an 20% respectively.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        originalBill = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.originalBill);
        Button btnTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTenPer);  // where your layout has a button with an id "buttonTenPer"
       btnTen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double bill = Double.parseDouble(originalBill.getText().toString());
                billWithTip = (bill * 0.10) + bill;
                String billString = String.valueOf(billWithTip);
                finalBill = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalBill);
                finalBill.setText(billString);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the error goes away, but it is not showing up in the TextView field when I click 10% button... I don't know why.

Comment: You have added onclicklistener to your edit text, where is your button defined?

Comment: The button is the onTen method. The listener is on the original bill field where the user first enters their bill amount. and the 10% is ... gosh you are right, the actual Id of the button is called btnTen, but I don't use it in the onTen method....how do I hook this up? Is the button supposed to have the listener instead?

Comment: Instead of originalBill.onClickListener -> change to button.onClickListener. Have a placed the button the layout. Example say you have a button in the layout with id:btnTenPercent. Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTenPercent); btw.onclickListener….

Comment: Thanks Bertilla! The user above was a tiny bit faster, so I went with that answer, but this was the problem. Thanks so much! I was unclear about how to hook up the listener and and the button.